# How to check whether a tag is present in XML file, using go?

Tags: xml, go

I don't know the tags that are present in the XML file. I'd like to know whether a certain tag exists.
For example, suppose the file is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tag1>
    <tag2></tag2>
</tag1>
<tag3/>
```

Here I'd like to check whether `tag2` exists. The only way to parse XML files using `go` is by defining `structs`, but for that, I'll have to know what tags are present in the file, which I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use *event-driven* XML parsing. Create an [`xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) using [`xml.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#NewDecoder), and parse the content of the XML by calling [`Decoder.Token()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Token) repeatedly (in a loop).

You can check if a token is a start element using a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), checking for the [`xml.StartElement`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#StartElement) type. If the assertion succeeds, you can check the name of the element if it matches the one you're looking for.

This is how it could look like:

```
func checkTag(src, tag string) (bool, error) {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(src))

    for {
        t, err := decoder.Token()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                return false, nil
            }
            return false, err
        }
        if se, ok := t.(xml.StartElement); ok {
            if se.Name.Local == tag {
                return true, nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(checkTag(src, "tag2"))
    fmt.Println(checkTag(src, "tagX"))
}

const src = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tag1>
    <tag2></tag2>
</tag1>
<tag3/>`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fUb0-l1hUKW)):

```
true <nil>
false <nil>
```

As you can see, `tag2` was properly found in the source XML, and `tagX` was properly not found.

See related question: [Unmarshalling heterogeneous list of XML elements in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987994/unmarshalling-heterogeneous-list-of-xml-elements-in-go/40991193#40991193)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use XPath and the [xmlpath](https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/xmlpath) package:

```
xml := `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><tag1><tag2>foo</tag2></tag1><tag3/>`

path := "/tag1/tag2"
compiledPath := xmlpath.MustCompile("/tag1/tag2")
root, err := xmlpath.Parse(strings.NewReader(xml))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if value, ok := compiledPath.String(root); ok {
    fmt.Printf("Found tag at path %v. Value: %v\n", path, value)

} else {
    fmt.Printf("Tag at path %v not found\n", path)
}
```

Comment: This requires you to know that `<tag2>` has a parent tag `<tag1>` (which is the "root"), which the asker doesn't know if I understood correctly.