# In Go, how to parse XML with mixed elements/chardata/elements/chardata content?

Tags: xml, go

Let's say I have a structure, that can reference elements
multiple times:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <book category="cooking">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
      Blah Blah Blah Bleh Blah of <year/> written by <author/>
    </book>
```

How can I parse this XML (or better to say, how can I describe the structure),
so that I can have these *internal references* to it?

```
    type Book struct{
       t string `xml:"book>title"`
       p string `xml:"book>price"`
       y string `xml:"book>year"`
       a string `xml:"book>author"`
       blah string ???????
    }
```

The naïve approach (https://go.dev/play/p/JVM98pCcI0D), just to describe `blah` as `cdata` is obviously wrong, because the references `<year/>` and `<author/>` are getting lost.

What is the right way to define `blah` here, so that the internal structure of it, is still available after parsing?

Comment: Something like this? https://go.dev/play/p/JVM98pCcI0D

Comment: Useful resource to construct Go struct definitions from XML - https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/

Comment: @icza: No, because as you can see (in the playground) the structure of `blah` is lost, and the question is how to do it in a such way, that the referenced elements in the field do not get lost

Comment: @IgorChubin You can't do it with a simple `Unmarshal()` call and struct. You have to do event-driven parsing and handle it yourself. An example of event parsing is here: [Unmarshalling heterogeneous list of XML elements in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987994/unmarshalling-heterogeneous-list-of-xml-elements-in-go/40991193#40991193)

Comment: @IgorChubin here's a solution based on icza's suggestion: https://go.dev/play/p/v8iZje6047n

Comment: @mkopriva Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on icza's comment:

```golang
func (b *Book) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }

        switch t := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            var f interface{} // field
            var r string      // replace
            switch t.Name.Local {
            case "title":
                f = &b.Title
            case "author":
                if len(b.Author) > 0 { // if "author" was already decoded then assume this is the element in the "blah chardata"
                    r = b.Author // if you want <author/> to appear in Text then do `r = "<author/>"` instead
                } else {
                    f = &b.Author
                }
            case "year":
                if len(b.Year) > 0 { // same logic as for author above
                    r = b.Year
                } else {
                    f = &b.Year
                }
            case "price":
                f = &b.Price
            }
            if f != nil {
                if err := d.DecodeElement(f, &t); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }
            if len(r) > 0 {
                b.Text += " " + r + " " // add empty space for padding the replacement string
            }
        case xml.CharData:
            s := strings.TrimSpace(string(t))
            if len(s) > 0 {
                b.Text += s
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```